# IdentityServer3 - PreAuthenticateAsync when logged in

Tags: c#, identityserver3

I have a situation where i need to pre-authenticate an already logged in user with IdentityServer3 so i can issue new claims.

As the user is already logged in and claims are requested, GetProfileDataAsync is called instead of PreAuthenticateAsync when i redirect.

I know i can override IsActive to determine if the user should be considered active, but it doesn't provide the passed in acr values for me too decide how to proceed.

```
public override Task IsActiveAsync(IsActiveContext context)
{
    context.IsActive = true; // <- context.SignInMessage.AcrValues not available
    return Task.FromResult(true);
}
```

Any advices on how i can proceed from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We currently don't have a way to invoke PreAuthenticate once the user is logged in. Maybe in a future release.